# The classic word-count algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Please... Guys , where am I going wrong here?

The classic word-count algorithm: given an array of strings, return a Map with a key for each
 different string, with the value the number of times that string appears in the array.

wordCount(["a", "b", "a", "c", "b"]) → {"a": 2, "b": 2, "c": 1}

wordCount(["c", "b", "a"]) → {"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1}

wordCount(["c", "c", "c", "c"]) → {"c": 4}

**My code so far**

```
function wordCount(arrayOfStrings) {
    const map = {};

    const arr = arrayOfStrings;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        let arr2 = arr.charAt(i);

        if (arr.indexOf(arr2) === arr.lastIndexOf(arr2)) {
            map.push({
                arr: arr2
            });
        }
    }
}

wordCount(["a", "b", "a", "c", "b"])
```

**and below is the test I'm to pass**

```
test(`Expect the wordCount of ["one", "fish", "two", "fish", "red", "fish", "blue", "fish"] to equal {one: 1, fish: 4, two: 1, red: 1, blue: 1}`, () => {
expect(wordCount([ 'one', 'fish', 'two', 'fish', 'red', 'fish', 'blue', 'fish' ])).toEqual({ one: 1, fish: 4, two: 1, red: 1, blue: 1 });
});

test(`Expect the wordCount of ["str", "hell", "str", "str"] to equal {str: 3, hell: 1}`, () => {
expect(wordCount([ 'str', 'hell', 'str', 'str' ])).toEqual({ str: 3, hell: 1 });
});

test(`Expect the wordCount of ["a", "b", "a", "c", "b"] to equal {"a": 2, "b": 2, "c": 1}`, () => {
expect(wordCount([ 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b' ])).toEqual({ a: 2, b: 2, c: 1 });
});

test(`Expect the wordCount of [1, "chair", "cane", "chair"] to equal {1: 1, chair: 2, cane: 1}`, () => {
expect(wordCount([ 1, 'chair', 'cane', 'chair' ])).toEqual({ 1: 1, chair: 2, cane: 1 });
});

test(`Expect the wordCount of ["ch", "chair", "cane", "chair", "ai", "ir"] to equal { ch: 1, chair: 2, cane: 1, ai: 1, ir: 1 }`, () => {
expect(wordCount([ 'ch', 'chair', 'cane', 'chair', 'ai', 'ir' ])).toEqual({ ch: 1, chair: 2, cane: 1, ai: 1, ir: 1 });
});
```

Comment: Another problem your code has is that your tests will not work; distinct objects are always not equal to each other, so your `.toEqual()` tests will fail (unless you're using some extremely odd testing framework).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of times specific characters are in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318976/how-to-count-the-number-of-times-specific-characters-are-in-a-string)

Comment: @sumit this is about strings in an array, not characters in a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well as it stands your approach is fundamentally wrong. All you need to do is add each string in the array as a property if it isn't one yet, and increment its value if it is.

```
function wordCount(arrayOfStrings) {
    const map = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; ++i) {
      if (arrayOfStrings[i] in map)
        map[arrayOfStrings[i]]++;
      else
        map[arrayOfStrings[i]] = 1;
    }

    return map;
}
```

That code checks each string in the array to see if it is already a property of the map (a plain object) that's under construction. If it is, the value is incremented; if it isn't, then a new property is created and initialized to 1.

It would be a little neater to use `.reduce()`:

```
function wordCount(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(map, word) {
    if (word in map)
      map[word]++;
    else
      map[word] = 1;
    return map;
  }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most concise and simple way is `reduce`:

```
const wordCount = arr => arr.reduce((a, c) => ((a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1), a), {});
```

Comment: Might be more concise, but not as readable as `arr => { let a = {}; for (let c of arr) a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1; return a; }`.

Comment: Well done. That is really amazing. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: No problem @Steve, always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (based on your code):

```
function wordCount(arrayOfStrings) {
    const map = {};
    const arr = arrayOfStrings;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        map[arr[i]] = (map[arr[i]] || 0) +1;
    }
    return map;
}
```